# Fade in with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a little script for a website I am developing. I am by no means a great coder but I feel like I got quite far with my limited knowledge. Now for my question. I have the following piece of code and its working but only partial. It seems to fade in an image on the page Y offset but sometimes it doesn't work. It either does not fade in, or when it is faded in. won't fade out when I scroll back to the top. Any help is appreciated!

HTML:

```
<img id="floatingi" class="vc_hidden-sm vc_hidden-xs alignnone wp-image-442 size-full" 
src="https://www.linkonderwijsadvies.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/temp2.png" alt="" 
width="305" height="650" />
```

CSS:

```
#floatingi{
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 1s;
}

#floatingi.fade {
opacity: 1;
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {

if (window.pageYOffset > 200){
document.getElementById('floatingi').classList.toggle('fade');
}});
</script>
```

I have also tried to copy this code to CodePen (and altered it a little so it would show a big Grey box instead of an image) but it seemed the problems persisted. So i don't believe it has anything to do with wordpress. Kind regards

## edit:

I have also tried something a little differant which seems to work better, but it doesnt fade in and out. here is the following code:

HTML:

```
<img id="floatingi" class="vc_hidden-sm vc_hidden-xs alignnone wp-image-442 size-full" 
src="https://www.linkonderwijsadvies.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/temp2.png" alt="" 
width="305" height="650" />
```

CSS:

```
#floatingi{
display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {

if (window.pageYOffset > 200){
document.getElementById('floatingi').style.display = "block";
}else{
document.getElementById('floatingi').style.display = "none";
}});
</script>
```

If anyone knows how to add a fade in/out to this, that would be awsome!
Kind regards!

Comment: Adding a `scroll` listener without debouncing it can cause serious performance issues.

Comment: Because as suggested in other comment and you don't have else part too.

Comment: so the if statement needs and '}else{ }'  and then leave that empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is this part of the code

```
if (window.pageYOffset > 200){
document.getElementById('floatingi').classList.toggle('fade');
}});
```

you are toggeling the class everytime so you add and then remove it again.

so you should just use classList.add and classList.remove

and as mentioned in the comments you should probably debounce the scroll event

Comment: Thanks! this seemed to work. I'm not sure on how to debounce (a novice coder at best) or if its needed. I'm working with wordpress so im not sure what functions are already working on the background. it's also a small website so posibly the performance will not be impacted too much since there isnt much to impact. Thank again!

Comment: @Roel take a look at https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function